# How to list ALL spreadsheets saved on/shared with Google Drive?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to make an application that lists all of the spreadsheet files which are saved on my google drive or which are shared with my google account.

I'm using the C# API V3 and my approach partly works. The problem is that it doesn't show all of the files, it only shows some (42 of them, to be precise. But when I look on my drive through a web-browser, I can see hundreds of spreadsheets either created by me or shared with me).

Here's how I initialize the service:

```
string[] scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata, SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
(
    new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "12345",
        ClientSecret = "54321"
    },
    scopes,
    "USER_NAME",
    CancellationToken.None
).Result;

var baseClientServiceInitializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = LIB_NAME + " v" + LIB_VERSION,
};

this.driveService = new DriveService(baseClientServiceInitializer);
```

Here's the List request:

```
List<File> allFilesOnDrive = new List<File>();

var listRequest = this.driveService.Files.List();
listRequest.PageSize = 25;
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(name, id)";
do
{
    FileList fileBulk = listRequest.Execute();

    allFilesOnDrive.AddRange(fileBulk.Files);
    listRequest.PageToken = fileBulk.NextPageToken;
} while (listRequest.PageToken != null);
```

After this runs, the *allFilesOnDrive* List has only 42 files in it. I can't see anything special about these particular 42 files, they're the same as the rest of them as far as I can tell.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whats wrong with your code are you sure there are more then 42 files on your drive account?  Note you should try using page streamer

```
var pageStreamer = new Google.Apis.Requests.PageStreamer<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File, FilesResource.ListRequest, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList, string>(
                                               (req, token) => request.PageToken = token,
                                               response => response.NextPageToken,
                                               response => response.Files);

var allFiles = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList();
allFiles.Files = new List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>();

foreach (var result in pageStreamer.Fetch(request))
        {
         allFiles.Files.Add(result);
        }
```

Code ripped from my [List all files on Google drive](http://www.daimto.com/list-all-files-on-google-drive/) tutorial

Searching is done by adding the Q parameter to your request.

> mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'